# Select tirando a diferença entre datas SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Queria um select que me desse a seguinte sentença comparando duas datas, exemplo:
`"2015-03-12 13:00"e "2015-03-12 14:15"`.

Meu retorno seria algo como:

> Falta 0 dias 1 hora e 15 minutos para...

Preciso disso em uma retorno sql.

Comment: "Preciso disso em uma retorno sql." Certeza? Dá pra fazer, mas é uma complicação usualmente desnecessária. Seria muito mais fácil fazer na parte da aplicação.

Answer (score 5):

Isso não vai formatar sua mensagem exatamente da forma que você quer, mas pode te ajudar a obter os valores separadamente para depois concatená-los em uma string e assim montar a mensagem final.

De acordo com [esta resposta do StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/289686/1639385) você pode usar um código semelhante ao seguinte:

```
SELECT julianday('2015-03-12 14:15') - julianday('2015-03-12 13:00')
```

[Esta outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34383293/1639385) dá exemplos de como obter a diferença em dias, horas, minutos ou segundos.

> Diferença em dias
>
> ```
> Select Cast (
>     JulianDay('2015-03-12 14:15') - JulianDay('2015-03-12 13:00')
> ) As Integer
> ```
>
> Diferença em horas:
>
> ```
> Select Cast ((
>     JulianDay('2015-03-12 14:15') - JulianDay('2015-03-12 13:00')
> ) * 24) As Integer
> ```
>
> Diferença em minutos:
>
> ```
> Select Cast ((
>     JulianDay('2015-03-12 14:15') - JulianDay('2015-03-12 13:00')
> ) * 24 * 60) As Integer
> ```
>
> Diferença em segundos:
>
> ```
> Select Cast ((
>     JulianDay('2015-03-12 14:15') - JulianDay('2015-03-12 13:00')
> ) * 24 * 60
> ```